# jsp не отображаются картинки

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        ">
 <!-- sets you your Spring context to allow for dispatching requests to Controllers. -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="by.onlinelibrary" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />



<!--Internalization -->
<bean id="messageSource"
class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
<property name="basename" value="/resources/msg/messages" />
<property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<mvc:interceptors>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
<property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>
</mvc:interceptors>

<bean id="localeResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
<property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>
 <context:component-scan base-package="by.onlinelibrary.controllers"/>
 <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

index.jsp

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>


        <img src="/resources/images/en.jpg"/>
      <%--<jsp:forward page="/val/reg"/>--%>
    </body>
</html>
```

не отображает картинку. Прошу помочь и объяснить что к чему.

Comment: Вы уверено, что верно привели листинг программы?
Просто в текущем варианте у Вас тег `<img src="/resources/images/en.jpg"` не закрыт

Comment: Копировал из другого документа на скорую руку. Там закрыт, извините за такое . вопрос остается открытым. Перерыл похожие вопросы, все равно не разобрался.

Comment: Попробуйте в теге `<img src="/resources/images/en.jpg"/>` первый слэш убрать.

Comment: все ровно не показывает

Comment: попробуйте тогда отдельно обратиться в браузере к картинке по url-у и посмотреть в логи спринга.

Comment: не находит. Создал не мавен проект, там все работает.  что это может быть?